# Filling dataframe where minimum interval is not satisfied

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of data at approximately 2 to 3 minutes interval. Sometimes the there are huge gaps in the data due to someone closing the monitoring software, say for few hours, and I would like to fill these gaps with an invalid marker if there's a >5 minute interval of missing data, so that I can present the data accordingly. How can I do that?

Edit: e.g.

```
Time a b c d
12:01 1 1 0 1
12:10 1 0 0 0
```

To something like

```
Time a b c d
12:01 1 1 0 1
12:06 -1 -1 -1 -1 or None or NaN
12:10 1 0 0 0
```

So that the part of the graph where there is no data is grayed out and not simply connecting the discontinuous data.

Not sure what the invalid symbols should be, what pandas like or what synergize well with plotting libraries

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want `NaN`'s every few minutes, not just one `NaN` in the gap, and that you don't mind adding `NaN`'s where there is no gap, as long as they're also added in the gap. Let me know if this solution does what you want:

```
# Imports

from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Setup

initial_index = [datetime(2014,4,21,12,x) for x in [0,5,8,14,18,21,25]]
columns = ['A','B','C','D']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7,4), index=initial_index, columns=columns)

# The actual solution

regular_interval_index = pd.date_range('12:00:00', '13:00:00', freq='5Min')

df_reindexed  = df.reindex(df.index + regular_interval_index)
```

The difference:

```
print df
                            A         B         C         D
2014-04-21 12:00:00  0.422272  0.539352 -0.401912  0.163993
2014-04-21 12:05:00  0.896098 -0.396894 -1.356148  0.724784
2014-04-21 12:08:00 -0.882721 -0.820098  0.154705 -0.706515
2014-04-21 12:14:00 -0.008495 -0.326866  1.115965 -1.559558
2014-04-21 12:18:00  0.117228  0.030347  1.049639 -0.536378
2014-04-21 12:21:00 -0.762874 -1.592967 -0.088216 -0.897630
2014-04-21 12:25:00 -0.483685  1.298545 -0.008885 -0.481165

[7 rows x 4 columns]

print df_reindexed
                            A         B         C         D
2014-04-21 12:00:00  0.422272  0.539352 -0.401912  0.163993
2014-04-21 12:05:00  0.896098 -0.396894 -1.356148  0.724784
2014-04-21 12:08:00 -0.882721 -0.820098  0.154705 -0.706515
2014-04-21 12:10:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:14:00 -0.008495 -0.326866  1.115965 -1.559558
2014-04-21 12:15:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:18:00  0.117228  0.030347  1.049639 -0.536378
2014-04-21 12:20:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:21:00 -0.762874 -1.592967 -0.088216 -0.897630
2014-04-21 12:25:00 -0.483685  1.298545 -0.008885 -0.481165
2014-04-21 12:30:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:35:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:40:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:45:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:50:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 12:55:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-04-21 13:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

[17 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: I think i would need the chart to break up at the NaNs so NaNs where there are no gaps might be a problem.

Comment: I don't think so. There's no data between 12:08:00 and 12:14:00 either way, whether the DataFrame contains `NaN`'s there or not. Now that I think about it, and after reading your question again, I'm not sure that you need this at all. What exactly are you trying to do and what about it is not working? Example code would be helpful.